# postgres-11: extension not found while getting version

Tags: postgresql-11, timescaledb

I added a new extension (timescaledb) like this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;
```

Then execute below command to see list of extensions:

```
select * from pg_extension;
```

And then remove a row in pg_extension which was related to `timescaledb`.

After that an abnormal bug happened and cann't even reconnect to my database in `dbeaver`, even trying via command line, then  was only able to connect to db but again can not run any commands because it says:

```
ERROR:  extension not found while getting version
```

I don't know what problem exactly happened and how to handle it.

**Update:**

To be sure, every one can reproduce this error, I created a new database, then with super-user privilege, repeated above commands to create extension and remove it like before. There again, the same issue raised.

This is my spec:

OS: centos7

postgres config comes from [pgtune](http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/)

postgres version:11

timescale version: 1.2 [follow this link for installation](https://docs.timescale.com/v1.2/getting-started/installation/rhel-centos/installation-yum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timescale person here.  Will need to understand more about your setup (which version of Timescale, which platform, which OS, etc.) to be able to help.

Please see the info we ask on our github:  https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/new/choose

But in general, the proper way in PG to remove an extension in `DROP EXTENSION`, not mucking with things internally in the `pg_extension` table (presumably with super-user permissions)?  I'm not sure what state you've left the database.